# How to get only current index and value of many html element using jquery click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm currently create an Ajax to delete any item from my list by using Jquery ajax.

Here is Html

```
<ul>
  <li><a class="del"><span style="display:none;">1</span></a></li>
  <li><a class="del"><span style="display:none;">2</span></a></li>
  <li><a class="del"><span style="display:none;">3</span></a></li>
  <li><a class="del"><span style="display:none;">4</span></a></li>
  <li><a class="del"><span style="display:none;">5</span></a></li>
  <li><a class="del"><span style="display:none;">6</span></a></li>
  <li><a class="del"><span style="display:none;">7</span></a></li>
  <li><a class="del"><span style="display:none;">8</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

As above html element I want to use Jquery click event to delete each item

```
 $('a.del').on('click',function(){
       //to delete any item when user click on each item of above code
       var relative = $('a.del').text();
       alert(relative);//Here it will get all a text 
     });
```

Please help

Comment: `$(this).text();`.....;)

Comment: you want if you click on 1 then 1 should be delete right?

Comment: @Yogesh Sharma Yes I will delete it one by one

Comment: why are the span hidden?

Comment: var relative = $(this).text(); relative.remove();

Comment: $('a.del').click(function () {
     alert($(this).parent().text());

 });

Comment: @Pekka

Yet this one thanks it work

Comment: @Cambodiachannel added index and value to the console.

Comment: Who vote me down what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hy98nu82/)

```
$('a.del').click(function () {
    console.log('value is '+$(this).parent().text());
    console.log('index is '+$(this).parent().index());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick:

```
$('li').on('click','a.del',function(){
   var relative = $(this).text();
   alert(relative);
   $(this).parent('li').remove();
});
```